# 430 Error on Date - itm.ReceivedTime in a subfolder

Tags: vba, datetime, outlook, office-automation

I get a 430 error running code on a subfolder of a shared inbox.

```vb
Sub GetEmails()

    'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
    'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
    Const NUM_DAYS As Long = 34
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim iRow As Long, oRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, sBody As String
    Dim mailboxName As String, inboxName As String, subfolderName As String
    
    mailboxName = "mailboxname"
    inboxName = "Inbox"
    subfolderName = "subfoldername"

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Folder = OutlookApp.Session.Folders(mailboxName) _
                     .Folders(inboxName).Folders(subfolderName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Folder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source folder not found!", vbExclamation, _
                "Problem with export"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    'add headers
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("Sender", "Subject", "Date", "Body")
    iRow = 2
    Folder.Items.Sort "Received"
    For Each itm In Folder.Items
        If TypeOf itm Is Outlook.MailItem Then       'check it's a mail item (not appointment, etc)
            If Date - itm.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then
                sBody = Left(Trim(itm.Body), 150)    'first 150 chars of Body
                sBody = Replace(sBody, vbCrLf, "; ") 'remove newlines
                sBody = Replace(sBody, vbLf, "; ")
                ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                    Array(itm.SenderName, itm.Subject, itm.ReceivedTime, sBody)
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next itm

    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

End Sub
```

I tried changing "itm" to "item". It works on the regular inbox. The issue happens when I try to pull from a subfolder.

I tried `Debug Print`. I don't know if I'm putting it in the right place.

The 430 error happens on the line:

```
If Date - itm.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then
```

If I try to pull 30 days worth of data, it will only pull like the last seven days. So it works but it is limited.

Comment: Just replied in your previous post on this. Does it always hangs on the same item(s)?  What if anything is different about those items?

Comment: Older items can be saved on the server, not locally. You could check if ReceivedTime of the oldest item found advances as time goes by

Comment: So When i originally started using the code in June, it worked fine until September. Nothing changed as far as i know. I checked the permissions on the inbox and the subfolder i was pulling from. The first time i faced this issue, i started working on a new sheet. It worked. After that i can only pull up to 7 days each time.

Comment: There is an odd workaround to another error, to reference `ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` For a shared inbox subfolder.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461846/run-time-error-when-accessing-subfolder-in-shared-inbox

Comment: Hey - doesnt look like the post above is trying to pull for a set number of days. Im trying to pull for the last 30 days each time.

Comment: What happens if you replace the reference to the subfolder with `ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Sort` method deals with non-existsing property:

```
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"
```

You need to use the [ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property instead.

Second, the sorted collection is lost and you continue dealing with unsorted one.

```
Folder.Items.Sort "Received"
    For Each itm In Folder.Items
```

Asking each time the Items property returns a new `Items` instance. So, you need to get an instance once and then re-use in the code. Only by following this way you will preserve the sorting order.

> The 430 error happens on the line:

```
If Date - itm.ReceivedTime <= NUM_DAYS Then
```

The error code indicates that [Class doesn't support Automation (Error 430)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/class-doesn-t-support-automation-error-430) which don't tell us anything meaningful.

Anyway, calculating dates that way to get items for specific dates in Outlook is not the best and proper way. Instead, you need to consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class which allows getting/dealing with items that correspond to your conditions only. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you could use the following search criteria to get items for a specific timeframe:

```
    'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) for more information.